# Custom icons/designs for online with other people?

Tags: software, websites

Somewhat of a peculiar question/request/search. 
Basically, I'm looking for any software/website/etc. where I can play chess with friends however the only caveat is that the icons/designs/board pieces/etc. be whatever I want them to be. Say having a strawberry for a king or a pawprint for a pawn for example. And that one side's icons be different from the other's (as in white king is a strawberry and black king is a shoe).

Answer (score 1):

Hi Anon and welcome to chess.stackexchange.

I would begin at [Peter Wong's virtual pieces site](http://www.virtualpieces.net/). Have a look at this, and if necessary contact Peter, who is very friendly and approachable.

All the best.